# Laravel ORM many to many relationship acts like one to many

Tags: php, laravel, orm

My problem is I am trying to establish a many to many relationship between posts and genre. Here is what I have done so far.

```
class Post extends Model
{

    public function genres()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Genre');
    }

}

class Genre extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }

}
```

genre Table

```
+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | News   |
|  2 | Sports |
+----+--------+
```

post table

```
+----+----------------+
| id |     title      |
+----+----------------+
|  1 | Political News |
|  2 | Sport Update   |
+----+----------------+
```

genre_post table

```
+----+---------+----------+
| id | post_id | genre_id |
+----+---------+----------+
|  1 |       1 |        1 |
|  2 |       1 |        2 |
|  3 |       2 |        2 |
+----+---------+----------+
```

When I am trying to acess genre list of a post, everything works fine.

```
Post::where('slug', '=', $id)->with("genres")->first(); // no problem
```

But when I tried the opposite it's not working.

```
$posts = Genre::where( "slug", "=", $id )->with("posts")->first();
```

I am getting the following error.

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'post.genre_id' in 'where
>   clause' (SQL: select * from `post` where `post`.`genre_id`

I understand the laravel is trying to aceess `genre_id` column from `post` table which doesn't exists since it's a many to many relation which means one post can contain more than one genre and one genre can contain more than one post.

Any idea how can I resolve this?

Comment: `hasMany` is the one to many relation, use `belongsToMany`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected since `hasMany` itself an one to many relationship. Use `belongsToMany` instead.

```
class Genre extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
    }

}
```